# Multiselect from tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want this code show result only friends of **$user_id** but I want to show results from friends and **$user_id**

```
SELECT *
FROM
  activity,
  friends
WHERE
  friends.user_id='$user_id'
  and activity.activity_user=friends.fr_id
ORDER BY activity.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html)

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM
  activity as t1
  join friends on t1.activity_user=friends.fr_id
WHERE
  friends.user_id='$user_id'
ORDER BY t1.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```